# How are the scores of GeneSplicer, MaxEntScan and SpliceRegion interpreted from VEP annotations?

Tags: machine-learning, ensembl

I am using [VEP](https://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/script/index.html) from Ensembl to annotate my VCF files with the extra plugins of [GeneSplicer](https://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/script/vep_plugins.html#genesplicer), [MaxEntScan](https://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/script/vep_plugins.html#maxentscan) and [SpliceRegion](https://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/tools/vep/script/vep_plugins.html#spliceregion). However, I don't fully understand the output of these scores.

I know that they are used for splicing predictions on trained sets.

- What are the range of these values ?
- What does a high or low value mean ?
- What is the threshold ?

Can someone please explain them please ?